# Arduino TTL jpeg Serial Camera and esp8266 wifi Wi-Fi module

Tags: arduino, camera, esp8266

I'm writing a code to take pictures if the distance is more than a certain distance after measuring the distance.

And send the distance data to Thingspeak, Store the photos on the SD card.

However, the program keeps stopping in the middle.

[Serial moniter capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eSOo.png)

Distance measurement and Thingspeak server data transfer / camera shooting were developed separately.

The two source codes worked normally independently.

But when the two codes are combined, there is an error.

Parts for Use : Arduino Uno, esp8266 wifi module, TTL Serial JPEG Camera with NTSC Video, 2Y0A21 Infrared Distance Sensor, Micro SD card adapter

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Adafruit_VC0706.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

#define DEBUG true
#define chipSelect 10

const int distancePin = 0;

String apiKey = "39R00EYW0BTKK5JJ";

SoftwareSerial esp8266(2, 3); //TX/RX 

#if ARDUINO >= 100

SoftwareSerial cameraconnection = SoftwareSerial(4, 5); //TX/RX

#else
NewSoftSerial cameraconnection = NewSoftSerial(4, 5);
#endif

Adafruit_VC0706 cam = Adafruit_VC0706(&cameraconnection);

int defaultDistance = 0;
int temp = 0;

void ThingspeakSendData(String alarmData);
void Snapshots();

void setup() {
    #if !defined(SOFTWARE_SPI)
    #if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
        if (chipSelect != 53) pinMode(53, OUTPUT); // SS on Mega
    #else
        if (chipSelect != 10) pinMode(10, OUTPUT); // SS on Uno, etc.
    #endif
    #endif

    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("VC0706 Camera snapshot test");//the program keeps stopping in the middle.

    if (cam.begin()) {
        Serial.println("Camera Found:");
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("No camera found?");
        return;
    }

    char *reply = cam.getVersion();
    if (reply == 0) {
        Serial.print("Failed to get version");
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("-----------------");
        Serial.print(reply);
        Serial.println("-----------------");
    }

    cam.setImageSize(VC0706_640x480);

    uint8_t imgsize = cam.getImageSize();
    Serial.print("Image size: ");
    if (imgsize == VC0706_640x480) Serial.println("640x480");
    if (imgsize == VC0706_320x240) Serial.println("320x240");
    if (imgsize == VC0706_160x120) Serial.println("160x120");

    esp8266.begin(9600);

    sendData("AT+RST\r\n", 2000, DEBUG); //reset module
    sendData("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n", 1000, DEBUG); //dual mode로 설정
    sendData("AT+CWJAP=\"0sangsiljangnim\",\"123456788\"\r\n", 5000, DEBUG); 

    // 2Y0A21
    analogReference(DEFAULT);
    pinMode(distancePin, INPUT);

    // distancePin 2Y0A21
    int raw = analogRead(distancePin);
    int volt = map(raw, 0, 1023, 0, 5000);
    int distance = (21.61 / (volt - 0.1696)) * 1000;
    defaultDistance = distance;
    Serial.println("Default : " + defaultDistance);
}

void loop() {
    // distancePin 2Y0A21 
    int raw = analogRead(distancePin);
    int volt = map(raw, 0, 1023, 0, 5000);
    int distance = (21.61 / (volt - 0.1696)) * 1000;
    Serial.println(distance);

    if (distance < defaultDistance)
    {
        String alarmData = "1";
        esp8266.listen();
        ThingspeakSendData(alarmData);

        cameraconnection.listen();
        Snapshots();
    }
    else if (distance == defaultDistance)
    {
        String alarmData = "0";
        esp8266.listen();
        ThingspeakSendData(alarmData);
    }

    delay(3000);
}

void ThingspeakSendData(String alarmData) {
    String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
    cmd += "184.106.153.149"; 
    cmd += "\",80";           
    esp8266.println(cmd);

    if (esp8266.find("Error")) {
        Serial.println("AT+CIPSTART error");
        return;
    }

    String getStr = "GET /update?api_key=";
    getStr += apiKey;
    getStr += "&field1=";
    getStr += String(alarmData);
    getStr += "\r\n\r\n";

    // Send Data
    cmd = "AT+CIPSEND=";
    cmd += String(getStr.length());
    esp8266.println(cmd);

    if (esp8266.find(">")) {
        esp8266.print(getStr);
    }
    else {
        esp8266.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
        // alert uesp8266
        Serial.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
    }
}

String sendData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug) {
    String response = "";
    esp8266.print(command); 
    long int time = millis();

    while ((time + timeout) > millis()) {
        while (esp8266.available()) {

            char c = esp8266.read(); 
            response += c;
        }
    }
    if (debug) {
        Serial.print(response);
    }

    return response;
}

void Snapshots() {
    Serial.println("Snap in 3 secs...");
    delay(3000);

    if (!cam.takePicture())
        Serial.println("Failed to snap!");
    else
        Serial.println("Picture taken!");

    if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
        Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
        return;
    }

    char filename[13];
    strcpy(filename, "IMAGE00.JPG");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        filename[5] = '0' + i / 10;
        filename[6] = '0' + i % 10;

        if (!SD.exists(filename)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    File imgFile = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);

    uint16_t jpglen = cam.frameLength();
    Serial.print("Storing ");
    Serial.print(jpglen, DEC);
    Serial.print(" byte image.");

    int32_t time = millis();
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT);

    byte wCount = 0; 
    while (jpglen > 0) {

        uint8_t *buffer;
        uint8_t bytesToRead = min(32, jpglen); 
        buffer = cam.readPicture(bytesToRead);
        imgFile.write(buffer, bytesToRead);
        if (++wCount >= 64) { 
            Serial.print('.');
            wCount = 0;
        }

        jpglen -= bytesToRead;
    }
    imgFile.close();

    time = millis() - time;
    Serial.println("done!");
    Serial.print(time); Serial.println(" ms elapsed");
}
```

Comment: Hi GENYF, and welcome to stack overflow. Can you show the output you get when you compile the code, and when you upload it to the Uno? Are you using the Arduino IDE? Is the baud rate of your serial monitor set to match the 9600 you've got in your code?

Comment: Yes. Arduino IDE is in use. All are equally 9600. Img link : https://ibb.co/rHP8MX9

Comment: you can't use two SoftwareSerial instances. only one can listen and you need to listen to both